# Upstart not loading services

Tags: server, upstart

I have a machine that boots no problem but a lot of the services do not start.

The run level when I login is "N 2".

Services can be manually started but not starting on boot.

I am running 10.04.3 with all latest updates.  I have found the following bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/497299?comments=all and nothing works there!

Here is the output from initctl --list too

```
mountall-net stop/waiting
rc stop/waiting
rsyslog start/running, process 766
screen-cleanup stop/waiting
tty4 start/running, process 782
udev start/running, process 386
upstart-udev-bridge start/running, process 382
ureadahead-other stop/waiting
vmware-tools stop/waiting
apport stop/waiting
console-setup stop/waiting
hwclock-save stop/waiting
irqbalance stop/waiting
plymouth-log stop/waiting
tty5 start/running, process 786
atd start/running, process 805
plymouth stop/waiting
ssh start/running, process 762
control-alt-delete stop/waiting
hwclock stop/waiting
module-init-tools stop/waiting
cron start/running, process 803
mountall stop/waiting
plymouth-stop stop/waiting
rcS stop/waiting
ufw start/running
mounted-varrun stop/waiting
rc-sysinit stop/waiting
tty2 start/running, process 790
udevtrigger stop/waiting
mounted-dev stop/waiting
tty3 start/running, process 791
udev-finish stop/waiting
hostname stop/waiting
mountall-reboot stop/waiting
mysql start/running, process 867
mountall-shell stop/waiting
mounted-tmp stop/waiting
network-interface (lo) start/running
network-interface (eth1) start/running
plymouth-splash stop/waiting
tty1 start/running, process 1266
udevmonitor stop/waiting
dmesg stop/waiting
network-interface-security (network-interface/eth1) start/running
network-interface-security (network-interface/lo) start/running
network-interface-security (networking) start/running
networking stop/waiting
procps stop/waiting
tty6 start/running, process 798
ureadahead stop/waiting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling some packages like the upstart and initscripts packages, etc.

Comment: OK, I will give that a go.  A few reboots and it seems to have fixed itself!